# c++ read from file redirection and also keyboard

Tags: c++

My program reads a list of integers from user input [ keyboard] and calculates some statistics

The user enters 'x' to terminate the input process.

So for example,

Enter integers separated by space ( enter x to quit) : 1 2 3 4 5 x

But now I want to include the inputs to be read from file redirection also.  So if the numbers followed by x is in a data file, the program should take it from there if not then prompt the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [isatty](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/isatty/) for your file descriptor
 (0 for standard input)

example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
main(){
  if(isatty(0))
    puts("tty");  // print some prompt
  else
    puts("pipe"); // not really needed in your case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read strings from a file with [fstream and iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Then from there you just parse the strings to see if they contain the correct data. If not, prompt the user for input?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you can either call your program with a file as a command line argument, or not, in which case you want it to read from standard input, you can do something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void run(std::istream& in) {
   // read all input from 'in' and run your program as normal
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   if(argc == 1) {
      run(std::cin);
   } else if(argc == 2) {
      std::ifstream fin(argv[1]);
      run(fin);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This way, if you call

```
./prog
```

it'll read from standard input (i.e., the keyboard), and if you call

```
./prog foo.txt
```

it'll read from the file `foo.txt`.

You may want to do a little more work when checking the command line arguments, but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

one approach that would *not require* any program alterations is to let the shell do the redirection for you.

On both Windows and Unix shells, < redirects a file to **stdin** for the program.

So, on unix/linux/mac on a console:

```
./app < file.txt
```

or windows, at the command prompt, just:

```
app < file.txt
```

will take the contents of *file.txt* and send it as **stdin** to the program called '*app*'.

Answer (score 0):

On a unix box the following should work:

```
progream <file
```

where program is your program and file contain the input that the user would type in.